# C# dont understand covariance and contravariance of delegates

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, covariance, contravariance

For a long time now I have been trying to understand the usefulness of the "in" and "out" parameters in connection with generics in C # and I just can't get it into my head(I know how often this question is asked on StackOverflow). I generally understand what covariance and contravariance is, just not why "in" and "out" parameters have to be used.

The following example:

```
public class MainClass {

delegate TOut MyDelegate<TIn, TOut>(TIn input);

public static void Main()
{
    // Func Delegate is using "in T, out TResult"
    Func<Dog, Mammal> funcDelegate = TestMethod;

    // not using "in" or "out" parameters
    MyDelegate<Dog, Mammal> myDelegate = TestMethod;
}

static Dog TestMethod(Mammal m) { return new Dog(); }

class Mammal { }
class Dog : Mammal { } }//end of class
```

Why does the Func delegate make use of "in" and "out" when my own delegate without "in" and "out" can also reference a method that is covariant and contravariant?

Comment: Your code in question is not compiling for me.

Comment: `TIn in` is invalid decalration, `in` is incorrect identifier here

Comment: First paragraph of [Variance in delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-delegates) will answer your question, _NET Framework 3.5 introduced variance support for matching method signatures with delegate types in all delegates in C#._ So, starting from .NET 3.5, your code is perfectly fine

Comment: @GuruStron Sorry, "in" should actually mean "input". That was a mistake when copying from Visual Studio. I have corrected it

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski So you could delete "in" and "out" from all delegate definitions today if there was no project < 3.5?

Comment: @Coco07 scroll down to the [Variance in Generic Type Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-delegates#variance-in-generic-type-parameters) part and _To enable implicit conversion, you must explicitly declare generic parameters in a delegate as covariant or contravariant by using the `in` or `out` keyword_ sentense. `In` and `out` are still needed for implicit conversion, but not for assigning a method to the delegates

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski That makes sense. I have certainly searched 200 similar entries on Google, but I never got this information provided by MS. Maybe I should take a Google course, thank you very much both! :)

Comment: @Coco07 I've added an answer summarizing the comments above with little explanataion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the comments under the question, the [Variance in Delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-delegates) document will explain that

> .NET Framework 3.5 introduced variance support for matching method
> signatures with delegate types in all delegates in C#. This means that
> you can assign to delegates not only methods that have matching
> signatures, but also methods that return more derived types
> (covariance) or that accept parameters that have less derived types
> (contravariance) than that specified by the delegate type.

So, your assignment `MyDelegate<Dog, Mammal> myDelegate = TestMethod;` is perfectly fine, despite different signatures on delegate and `TestMethod` (reversed input parameter and return type).

But `in` and `out` parameters are still needed when you have an implicit conversion between delegates, according to [Variance in Generic Type Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-delegates#variance-in-generic-type-parameters) section

> To enable implicit conversion, you must explicitly declare generic
> parameters in a delegate as covariant or contravariant by using the in
> or out keyword.

E.g. the following code will not compile

```cs
MyDelegate<Dog, Mammal> myDelegate = TestMethod;
MyDelegate<Dog, Dog> anotherDelegate = TestMethod;
myDelegate = anotherDelegate; //error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type...
```

Until you declare `MyDelegate` witn contravariant parameter and covariant return type

```cs
delegate TOut MyDelegate<in TIn, out TOut>(TIn input);
```

After that last line will compile

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [@Pavel Anikhouski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4728685/pavel-anikhouski) comment (linking [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-delegates) article), variance will come into play when you will try to do next, for example:

```
Func<Mammal, Mammal> someFunc = TestMethod;
Func<Dog, Mammal> funcDelegate = someFunc;
MyDelegate<Mammal, Mammal> someDelegate = TestMethod;
MyDelegate<Dog, Mammal> myDelegate = someDelegate; // will not compile unless you will declare MyDelegate<in TIn, TOut>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I have understood it now or can at least continue reading the right direction :)

Comment: Honestly, this "answer" doesn't add anything new to points, already stated in mentioned article and comments under the question. It seems to be a rep points hunting only

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I would have marked your comment as accepted if it had been written as an answer - gladly still

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I have started writing it before seeing your comment, and, TBH have not read the article past the quote you've added to the first comment. Also agree with that your comments are good as an answer and you should have added it originally.